# I can't get the chessboard in the correct colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a color black and then a color white, but some colors come together horizontally, and I didn't want it to stay that way. I want to create a board from a loop.

Could anyone help?

```js
 var tab = document.querySelector('.grid-container')
    for (let i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            tab.innerHTML += '<div class="grid-item black">'+i+'</div>'
        } else {
            tab.innerHTML += '<div class="grid-item white">'+i+'</div>'
        }        
    }
```

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 50px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 50px);
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.black{
    background-color: black;
}

.white {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
  
</div>
    <script src="./board.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a second `for` loop to easily distinguish rows and cols.

Then we can use the following `if` to check for black/white squares:

```js
if ((i + j) % 2) {
    tab.innerHTML += '<div class="grid-item black">'+n+'</div>'
} else {
    tab.innerHTML += '<div class="grid-item white">'+n+'</div>'
}
```

---

```js
var tab = document.querySelector('.grid-container')

for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        let n = 1 + (i * 8 + j);
        if ((i + j) % 2) {
            tab.innerHTML += '<div class="grid-item black">'+n+'</div>'
        } else {
            tab.innerHTML += '<div class="grid-item white">'+n+'</div>'
        }     
    }
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 50px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 50px);
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.black{
    background-color: black;
}

.white {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container"></div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `let n = i + j;` be `let n = i * j;`?

Comment: Yea I was still sleeping ;)

Comment: Or `(i + 1) * (j + 1)` now you've started the loops from 0.

Comment: cool, i'll test it here

Comment: Conventionally it's done using `(i + j) % 2` but this works as well :)